# Executing T-sql query from hard drive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have T-SQL queries stored on a hard drive: `I:\queries\query1.sql` and `I:\queries\query2.sql`.

I usually work in a way that I execute a query from a drive, and then I copy results into `Excel`, and then I work on it.

My problem here is that `query1.sql` is already long, and now I would like to extend it by getting a result of `query2.sql`, and join it with a result of `query1.sql`.

What I could do is appending a code from `query2.sql` to `query1.sql`. But then the query is getting really long and hard to maintain.

I would like to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ("Result of I:\queries\query1.sql") q1 
LEFT JOIN ("Result of I:\queries\query2.sql") q2 ON q1.ID=q2.ID
```

Is there any way to write a query or stored procedure, which will be again stored on a drive to do this?

Comment: Storing them on the hard drive is a little odd, why not store them in the database?

Comment: Why are you writing queries like that in the first place? Seems like an odd idea. if you were storing them in the RDBMS you could make use of views, stored procedures and functions. That would make your life infinitely easier.

Comment: Ideally, you *compose* queries together and let *the database system* worry about whether it can/should store intermediate results, etc. You're currently thinking very *procedurally* (first I'll do (a), then I'll do (b), etc), which is not the right mindset for working with *sets*.

Comment: I do it as I'm not allowed store in the RDBMS. I have only a read access. I'm aware this is not a best approach but I'd like to be at least as efficient as possible.

Comment: A view is a bit easier to reuse, but as we don't know what the queries look like, that may not be possible

Comment: You can combine the two queries using the `WITH` keyword. I know you have a huge query to maintain but they are still effectively separated, they're just in one file. Or you could go way out and use something like Power BI that lets you join and clean data from queries. Or you could try using some other free data store to stage your data. Or you could pass the request up the line to get more substantial analytics tools. Or you could ask for your own scratch database on the same SQL Server and just do cross database queries.

Comment: There's plenty of examples, but... `WITH T1 AS (<paste query1.sql in here>), T2 AS (<paste query2.sql in here>) SELECT * FROM Q1 LEFT JOIN Q2 ON Q1.ID=Q2.ID`

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you need to ask your DBA for a database when you *are* able to store things in the database.  This can be on the same system where the data is stored.  Or, it could be on a linked system.  Gosh, you could run SQL Server locally and store the information and data there.

Then, the queries that you are storing in files should be views in the database.  You can then run the queries and store and combine the results locally.

You are essentially recreating database functionality using text files and data files -- going through a lot of effort when SQL Server already supports this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Gordon's comment (+1), **why** are you running scripts off of a drive?  Most DBA's I've known would treaten bodily harm over this as executing code that they can't control / troubleshoot / see source code control on brings a whole host of security and supportability issues.

Far better to store this code in a Stored Procedure, which will have a saved query execution plan, can be tracked using various DMV's, and have permissions assigned to it, then your outside Excel doc can just set a connection and execute the SP.

Comment: This is pretty common, where I work for non-IT people like me. I either run queries stored on my drive or through connection from Excel or R (where I have to hardcode a query anyway).